# Cannot initialize a variable of type - linking error

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es

I copy some code from another project and I work fine in previous project but in new project I get linking error:

OpengLWaveFrontCommon.h:50:22: 
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'VertexTextureIndex *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'
        **VertexTextureIndex *ret = malloc(sizeof(VertexTextureIndex));**

This file (OpengLWaveFrontCommon.h) is a part of openGL iPhone project: Wavefront OBJ Loader. https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff

Should I make some special flag or something, because it is C structured?

```
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>

typedef struct {
    GLfloat red;
    GLfloat green;
    GLfloat blue;
    GLfloat alpha;
} Color3D;

static inline Color3D Color3DMake(CGFloat inRed, CGFloat inGreen, CGFloat inBlue, CGFloat inAlpha)
{
    Color3D ret;
    ret.red = inRed;
    ret.green = inGreen;
    ret.blue = inBlue;
    ret.alpha = inAlpha;
    return ret;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Vertex3D
#pragma mark -
typedef struct {
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;
} Vertex3D;

typedef struct {
    GLuint  originalVertex;
    GLuint  textureCoords;
    GLuint  actualVertex;
    void    *greater;
    void    *lesser;

} VertexTextureIndex;


static inline VertexTextureIndex * VertexTextureIndexMake (GLuint inVertex, GLuint inTextureCoords, GLuint inActualVertex)
{
    VertexTextureIndex *ret = malloc(sizeof(VertexTextureIndex));
    ret->originalVertex = inVertex;
    ret->textureCoords = inTextureCoords;
    ret->actualVertex = inActualVertex;
    ret->greater = NULL;
    ret->lesser = NULL;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Is that compiled as C++ or Objective-C++? If yes, you should add that (important) information to your question. - And btw, that is a *compiler* error, not a *linker* error.

Comment: Where can I see with witch compiler the file is compiled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cause Of Issue:**

`malloc()` returns a pointer of type `void *`, you need to type cast it to corresponding data-type.

> malloc returns a void pointer to the allocated space, or NULL if there
>   is insufficient memory available. To return a pointer to a type other
>   than void, use a type cast on the return value. The storage space
>   pointed to by the return value is guaranteed to be suitably aligned
>   for storage of any type of object that has an alignment requirement
>   less than or equal to that of the fundamental alignment.

Reference [**malloc()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d.aspx)

**Fix for the Issue:**

```
VertexTextureIndex *ret = (VertexTextureIndex *)malloc(sizeof(VertexTextureIndex));
```

Comment: Thanks this solution work! I post another question downstairs, can you be so nice and look if is some stupid mistake as here, please?

Comment: Note that casting the return value of malloc() is only necessary if the file is compiled as C++ (or Objective-C++). In plain C or Objective-C, it is *not necessary* and - as far as I know - bad style. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc.

Comment: Can I chose with witch compiler should the file be compiled, because in previous project the file does not return any error

Comment: @user1436690: sorry, I was not at my desk :) What's your question, is that about compiler ? You can change the compiler settings in your IDE, but both GCC and LLVM compilers will show this error (probably)